# elasticsearch - Bulk insert/update request with conditional if

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, bulk

We have base database where the Candidate records are created/updated/deleted. In elasticsearch we are using es generated ID. However database do not know the ES ID generated for the record. In a batch process we are fetching the 500 records from DB and sending them to ES but we do not know which records needs to insert and which record needs to update. Also we do not know the ES ID of already updated records.

Using CURL request in BULK is there any way we can first check whether the record is present or not using unique email address of each record. If it is present then send Update request or if it is not present then send Insert request.

Is there any way we can write the script inside the BULK call?

Regards,
Jayesh Bhoyar

Comment: Do you have any way to use an existing DB ID? Or maybe even use a hash of the email address as the ID.

Comment: Thank you.. As posted in other question we read that custom ID generation impacts on search thats why we are planning to go with elastic generated ID. And that's why I raised this question.

Comment: I dont understand why custom ID generation has impacts on search. I would always go with the correct primary key from the primary datastore, keeping consistency between the two will otherwise turn into a nightmare.

Comment: Hi All, We have used custom ID as elastic ID but with 20 Zero Padded numbers as per lucene friendly.
if Candidate ID is 1 then we have created elasticsearch ID as 00000000000000000001

Comment: Thank you for all your help